# Variable declaration, declare as Deque or ArrayDeque = new ArrayDeque();

Tags: java, variable-declaration

I'm not sure what the difference between the following declarations are :

```
ArrayDeque ad = new ArrayDeque();
Deque d = new ArrayDeque();
```

Is one of them more proper than the other? Or are there situations where you would in fact use one over the other. I realize that ArrayDeque implements Deque but I'm not sure how that plays into the above declarations.

Thanks

Comment: This is a lot more specific than the other question. That's about interfaces, this is about two libraries.

Comment: @AnubianNoob Which libraries? How is `Deque` vs `ArrayDeque` different from `List` vs `ArrayList`? I don't see any difference between this question and the duplicate.

Comment: @AnubianNoob `ArrayDeque` is an implementation of the `Deque` interface.  They are _not_ two different libraries.  This is exactly like `ArrayList` and `List`.

Comment: Fair enough, I was just thinking this question is a lot narrower in scope than the other one. I guess they're close enough that the other one solves this.

Comment: just to follow up then, is there any scenario where it might be acceptable (or where you should)  use  

ArrayList myList = new ArrayList();
instead of 
List myList = new ArrayList();

is it just the intuition that since ArrayList is by definition a List, it's best/proper to declare all ArrayList as Lists?